# A topological space is trivial iff every function to it is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

If $Y$ has the trivial topology $\tau_Y = \{\emptyset, Y\}$, then for every topological space $X$, and every map $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $f$ is continuous, because the preimage of the two open sets of $Y$ is open in $X$. I wonder if the converse is true: 
Given a set $Y$ such that, for every topological space $X$ and for every function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, $f$ is continuous, then $\tau_Y = \{\emptyset, Y\}$ ? Is it possible to construct a function such that the only open sets in $Y$ are $Y$ and $\emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose that $\tau_Y$ is not trivial, and let $U\in\tau_Y\setminus\{\varnothing,Y\}$. Now look at the identity map from $Y$ with the indiscrete topology to $\langle Y,\tau_Y\rangle$, and consider the inverse image of $U$ under this map.

Comment: The identity map between any two topological spaces $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(X, \tau_2)$ is continuous iff $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$. But in this case, this gives an absurd, because we have that the topology in the target space is less finer than the trivial topology. Thanks, that was clarifying.

Comment: @Bruno: You’re welcome.